# SSRS: How can I get a dynamic list of values from a dataset column and a running count in ParentGroup footer

Tags: reporting-services

I have some data that has a result of a source or reason.  They can be anthing in a long list of options, but I only want to count those that appear in the query results as a list with totals.

Example:

| Property | Reason |
| --- | --- |
| PropA | Google |
| PropA | Referral |
| PropA | Billboard |
| PropA | Referral |
| PropA | NULL |

In the Parent Row Group footer I would like to list each Reason that shows in the result set with a count, like a pivot table

| Reason | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Google | 1 |
| Referral | 2 |
| BillBoard | 1 |

...

I'm not really sure where to start.  I could do it as a subreport, but if I can do it with only the one query I would prefer that.  Thoughts?  I thought of a LIST but not sure how to take the list and get a count.  I'm kind of newish to SSRS, coming over from Crystal.

I've looked at a list but struggled with counts.  Triend Column Group which gives an error on column span.  Can do it in a subreport but prefer other methods if possible.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm missing something here but to get the results you showed, why not just have a group by `Reason` and `=COUNTROWS("myReasonRowGroupNameHere")` as the textbox expression. If I've misunderstood, please edit your question and include all relevant info. In SSRS the position of a control (tablix, textbox etc.) can make a big difference to what expressions will work so if this is part of a larger tablix/matrix etc then best you show that too.

Comment: Sorry tried to be too basic.  there are several columns and I have it grouped by that.  The final row is the reason that I would need to create some type of dynamic lost from and then count how many instances in that Parent group.
Property (ParentGroup)
 - Month (Child Row Group)
   - Unit  (Grandchild Row group)

Each of these row group have a total footer.    I'll have to get a screen shot of the set up.